# Can I edit a script to rerun based on url/field input?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I have a script that gets a streams link based on the external html page.

Is there a way to have one script and a resourced page with links to all the external links or do I need to have an individual page per request?

In other words, can I do this

```
example.com/videos.php?v=1234
```

or must I use

```
example.com/eachVideoPage.php
```

Here is the script I use to get the link.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/xmpegURL");


?>
<?php
ob_start(); // ensures anything dumped out will be caught
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/aVideoPage.html");

preg_match_all(
    '/(http:\/\/[^"].*?\.mp4)[",].*?/s',

    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[1];


// clear out the output buffer
while (ob_get_status())
{
    ob_end_clean();
}

// no redirect
header("Location: $link");
}

?>
```

Comment: [_GET](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and/or [_POST](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) will do what you want assuming you aren't using another framework that has different ways of handling requests, custom routing etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want to do is change the `file_get_contents()` URL It should be as simple as:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/xmpegURL");

$vid = htmlspecialchars($_GET["v"]);

ob_start(); // ensures anything dumped out will be caught
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/$vid/aVideoPage.html");

preg_match_all(
    '/(http:\/\/[^"].*?\.mp4)[",].*?/s',

    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[1];


// clear out the output buffer
while (ob_get_status())
{
    ob_end_clean();
}

// no redirect
header("Location: $link");
}

?>
```

Updates:
`$vid = htmlspecialchars($_GET["v"]);`

Using [_GET](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) will take the URL Query parameters and do whatever you want with them. In this case a basic value assignment looking for `?v=123` in the URL. (`$vid === '123'`)

It is worth mentioning that you should add some code to handle cases where `?v` does not exists, or contains malicious input (depending on who uses it)

Then just reuse the value in the URL you want to call:

`$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/$vid/aVideoPage.html");`

**Update after comments**

In order to call another site with a query string you can simply append it to the URL:

`$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/aVideoPage.html?v=$vid");`

This will depend entirely on the remote site you are calling however. `.html` files usually won't do anything with query strings unless there is JavaScript in the code that uses it. But generally if you can browse to the remote URL with `?v=1234` in the URL and it selects the right video, then the above should also work.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Forgive me, but where do I store the values for v=? Should I create separate pages based on categories or 1 big file that contains all the values?

Comment: so if the code above is `example.com/videos.php` and you then navigate to `example.com/videos.php?v=1234` the `$vid` variable in the code example will store the value `1234` for that single request, you can then call `example.com/videos.php?v=1235` etc without having to change the code in `videos.php`

Comment: Jake you are so close to helping me understand this and I am thus far grateful! So if I may, how do I tie in an external url to the value for instance v=1234? In other words, how can I say example.com/videos.php?v=1234 actually means other.example.com/theVideoPage.html?

Comment: @norcaljohnny, See updated answer. If you are re-using it to call a remote site it will depend entirely on how the remote site handles the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: @norcaljohnny store the url/video info in a database, possibly with tag information or keywords of some sort, then you can use one php file to allow searching,showing by tag/category, etc.  but this starts branching into "how to solve problems with programs and systems" and "how to program" vs. "how to fix what is wrong with this bit of code" ...